# Error when I run my project using grails run-app

Tags: grails

Why am I getting this error when i use `grails run-app`?

> Error 2014-03-03 13:31:30,283 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:
>   Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
>   such property: min for class: org.example.shalu.Task Possible
>   solutions: id, all Message: Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
>   such property: min for class: org.example.shalu.Task Possible
>   solutions: id, all

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you will see that you are trying to reference `min` on the class `org.example.shalu.Task` which doesn't exist. It's possible that you are doing something in `Bootstrap.groovy`?

Comment: ya in constrains i set min=0L instead of min:0L thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a Service which is does not have a coordinating logic between domain classes (that means there is no domain class for that service).

If this is the case, then add : static transactional = false to the service.

```
class MyService {
    **static transactional = false**
}
```

More info: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html

Comment: Services are not coupled to particular domain classes.

Answer (score -1):

oh this one comes when your `database` `setting`

either `not` mapped with exact 
``` database`` ```server`running , 
grails can cannot connect to it , check 
your`password`and`
username`and 
check your`database name
`check your`data source setting` 
And check your connection String URL on datasource like

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDB"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "yourUser"
    password = "yourPassword"
}
```

DUDE!!